# INT 10h function 0Dh inconsistent

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086

I am trying to get the color of a single pixel (I'm using 13h graphics mode in Emu8086), for that I'm using function 0Dh of interrupt 10h. But it is not consistent at all. It fails to give the correct color of the pixel and gives me 00 (black).

I'm aware that CX is doubled in mode 13h. But I highly suspect that the problem is the shape I drew (two filled rectangles), which happens to be titled 45 degrees counter clock wise.

What seems to be the problem? And how to get the color of a single pixel consistently?

[image: The shape]

```
.MODEL SMALL
.DATA

X DW ?
Y DW ?
T DW ?
linecounter dw ?

LastX DW ?
LastY DW ?

PixelClr DB ?
.CODE
.STARTUP 


MOV AH, 00
MOV AL, 13h
INT 10h

MOV X, 85
MOV Y, 93
MOV linecounter, 75

Square4Top:
MOV BH, 0
MOV CX, X
MOV DX, Y
MOV T, 7
MOV AH, 0Ch
MOV AL, 01h

DrawSquare4Top:
INT 10h

INC CX
INC DX
DEC T
CMP T, 0
JNZ DrawSquare4Top

INC X
DEC Y
DEC linecounter
CMP linecounter, 0
JNZ Square4Top



MOV X, 61
MOV Y, 93
MOV linecounter, 50

Square5Top1: 
MOV BH, 0
MOV CX, X
MOV DX, Y
MOV T, 7
MOV AH, 0Ch
MOV AL, 0Bh

DrawSquare5Top1:
INT 10h

INC CX
INC DX
DEC T
CMP T, 0
JNZ DrawSquare5Top1

INC X
DEC Y
DEC linecounter
CMP linecounter, 0
JNZ Square5Top1



;;;
;;; INITIALIZE MOUSE
;;;


MOV AX, 0
INT 33h 

MOV AX, 1
INT 33h

MOV AX, 2
INT 33h  

MouseAgain:
MOV AX, 3
INT 33h

CMP BX, 1 
JNZ MouseAgain    
MOV AH, 0Dh
MOV BH, 00
SHR CX, 1
INT 10h
MOV PixelClr, AL

JMP MouseAgain   

END
```

Comment: I modified your source to exit when colour is non zero (`test al,al` `jz MouseAgain` `mov ah,4Ch` `int 21h`) and after some frantic clicking the app eventually terminated (tasm + dosbox, I don't own emu8086) (I also removed the `hide cursor call`, the dosbox VGA has surprisingly nice "hw" arrow for 320x200 mode, with reasonable drawing, although I'm not sure which coordinate is returned as cursor position). BTW your screenshot shows the shapes filled, but in dosbox I see them with "chequered" fill, i.e. every next pixel is black, so it's even harder to click coloured pixel.

Comment: easy way to check: after reading the pixel, set it again to the color you've read. the picture shouldnt change. if it does, you may get a clue why (value scaling, mapping mouse pixel <-> screen pixel, or whatever)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to tell what you're doing wrong since *you haven't actually shown us your code!*

However, you should at least ensure that you have set *all* relevant registers (see [here](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0105.htm))  before invoking the interrupt. This means all of:

```
AH = 0Dh
BH = page number
CX = column
DX = row
```

And, of course, you may *actually* be looking at a black pixel there, particularly since most of the screen *is* black. I'd be checking whether you're looking at a pixel that's just outside the shape, something like `x` instead of `y` in the following "graphic":

```
      /\
     /  \
   x/   /
   /y  /
  /   /
 /   /
/   /
\  /
 \/
```

That should be fairly easy to check if you fill the entire screen with white before drawing your rectangles, and see if you get back white or still get black.

Comment: Hey there. I checked all relevant registers, same problem. Here's a snippet of the code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/261f9ed74b7bda7d6357f581c3bd3d54

Basically, the code starts by drawing the two shapes, initializes the mouse, when left mouse is clicked it takes the coordinates of the mouse pointer and checks the pixel color there and saves the pixel color in a variable. 

**NOTE:** I provide function 0Dh with the pixel coordinates, not columns and rows (I tried, it fails horribly).

Comment: @YoZo, can't see anything *obviously* wrong with your code, you may want to store the actual `cx/dx` you get back from int33 to see if they seem valid. Also, I re-iterate, set the entire screen to white for a test to see if it's returning black no matter what the color is.

Comment: @YoZo I don't see `ds` setup in your code, but you are using `.model small` (i.e. EXE file), where data segment and code segment are not the same. Maybe you are checking wrong memory value in debugger, try `ds:PixelClr` (I mean real `ds`, your actual value).  ... EDIT: oh wait, maybe that's hidden in `.STARTUP` directive/macro/whatever *that* is...

Comment: @paxdiablo I inverted the screen to white and then drew the shapes. I get 0Fh (white) as the pixel color. Turns out, that it gives me the background's color not the pixel itself. Any solution?

Comment: @YoZo don't use mouse coordinates, but call `int 10h` get pixel directly with coordinates, where you know there is coloured pixel. But I'm pretty sure your code works, if white is returned, so your problem is not-sure-what, either emu8086 has not this function emulated properly (unlikely, as it returns white pixels), or you're always hitting the white ones with mouse? As there so few coloured in the chequered scheme, it's not that easy to hit coloured one. Maybe draw bigger filled rectangles. Like full 320x200 of `(x>>4)+(y>>4)` colour (will create 16x16 tiles with different colours).